# Desabilitar data escolhida no DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem? Gostaria de saber se é possível, através do DatePickerDialog, desabilitar datas que usuários escolheram? Tipo, usuários escolhem uma data no datepicker que não pode mais aparecer para outros usuários, como em salões de cabeleleiros, que não pode ter a mesma vaga para duas pessoas. Cheguei até a parte de criar o DatePickerDialog, porém, não sei como desabilitar estas datas após escolhidas pelos usuários.

```
 diaAgendamento= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDataInicial);
    diaAgendamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int ano = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, datePicker, dia, mes, ano);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    datePicker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            diaAgendamento.setText(date);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar esta biblioteca  [Material Date Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options), nela você pode setar uma opção para mostrar datas específicas.

**Exemplo**

```
datePicker.setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

Passando um `array` de `Calendar` como um parâmetro que contem todas as datas que podem ser selecionadas.

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil se usar `setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta de vocês, me ajudou. Só estou com uma dúvida: estou colocando o compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1' no meu build.gradle e mesmo assim não estou conseguindo chamar o setDisableDays.